# insert math functions in math function

Tags: r, function, math

I want to:

1. insert (functional) arguments into a mathematical function
2. simplify the resulting expression algebraically

**Example**

```
func1 <-function(x,y) {
   return((x^3-3*x*y))
}

#input x=1/n and y=1/n
#the desired result should be
#1st: (1/n)^3-3*(1/n)*(1/n)
#2nd: 1/n^3 - 3/n^2 = 1/n^2*(1/n - 3)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(Ryacas)

n <- ysym("n")
x <- 1/n
y <- 1/n
simplify(x^3-3*x*y)
## y: ((-3)*n^3+n^2)/n^5
```